# Canvas LMS : the file uploaded can not be previewed or downloaded

Tags: canvas-lms

I am using Canvas LMS under AWS EC2 (Amazon Web Services). and I can upload some files there, but they seem not previewed or downloaded. So I want to know what the problem is.  here link is my screenshot:

[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVl4f.png) 
[photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5vOp.png)

(only file name is there, but can not be opened !)